# Div with auto height does not work

Tags: css, html

I'm having trouble letting the height of the div automatic. Where the text is great, just passing the div. How do I stop the automatic height?

See the problem:

http://noivascearenses.com.br/novo/?n=categoria&id=6

```
.categoria {
border: 1px solid #F9F7F6;
background: url(../imagens/prod-bg.png) repeat left top;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #DCDAD9;
margin: 0px 6px 10px 6px;
height: 235px;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: add your code here....

Comment: post your code in a fiddle please. a link to your site helps no one in the future if the site changes.

Comment: It seems that work fine with Firefox but having issue in chrome. right?

Comment: Right! Does not work in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to categoria .

```
display: inline-table;
```

Check the image by adding display as inline-table. Try this one may be it will solve your problem.

Or another approach is like to set height of div programmatically by calculating the contents character

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are using `float` on the elements inside `.categoria` in order to make the height work depending on the content you need to **`clear`**  the floated elements add this on your css:

```
.categoria:after {
    display:block;
    content:" ";
    clear:both;
}
```

Also in this link you have more options on how to clear your floats :

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

*Don't forget to remove the fixed height you are setting in the class `.container` and inline*

Comment: @RonaldAraújo you have to remove the height declarations for that div ... in the class .container and the inline one

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to implement your answer! :)